# How to find files with a specific pattern in the parent and child directory?

Tags: linux, files, grep, find, cygwin

How to find files with a specific pattern in the parent and child directory of my present working directory using a single command ?

Filename - *test.txt*, the file has the pattern `nslookup`

This file is present in 3 directories and they are */home*, */home/1* and */home/1/2*

I am currently at */home/1*. I have tried below commands :

```
find ../ -type f -name "test.txt"
```

Output :

```
../test.txt
../home/1/test.txt
../home/1/2/test.txt
```

I was able to find the files, hence I tried the below command :

```
$ find ../ -type f -exec grep "nslookup" {} \;
nslookup
nslookup
nslookup
```

This doesn't display the file names.

Command :

```
find . -type f -name "test.txt" | xargs grep "nslookup"
```

==> gives me files in pwd and child directories :

```
./1/test.txt:nslookup
./test.txt:nslookup
```

but when I try to search in the parent directory as shown below the results are erroneous :

```
find ../ -type f -name "test.txt" | xargs grep "nslookup"

User@User-PC ~/test
$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-6.1 User-PC 2.5.2(0.297/5/3) 2016-06-23 14:29 x86_64 Cygwin
```

Comment: Have you tried `grep -irn`?

Comment: @vol7ron - my kids love your username 8-). Good taste in using the original image for your profile.

Comment: That’s sweet! :D <3

Answer (score 4):

Your command

```
find ../ -type f -exec grep "nslookup" {} \;
```

is almost correct, apart from the fact that `grep` by default does not display the filename when it is given only a single file to work with.

Here are two ways of fixing this:

1. Using a `grep` that has the non-standard (but common) `-H` option to always display the filename:

   ```
   find ../ -type f -exec grep -H 'nslookup' {} \;
   ```
2. Giving `grep` at least two filenames:

   ```
   find ../ -type f -exec grep 'nslookup' /dev/null {} \;
   ```

If you are interested in *only* the filenames, then these are two ways of doing this:

1. Use the standard `-l` option with `grep`:

   ```
   find ../ -type f -exec grep -l 'nslookup' {} \;
   ```
2. Let `find` output the pathname of the file if it contains a match:

   ```
   find ../ -type f -exec grep -q 'nslookup' {} \; -print
   ```

   Here, we only use `grep` to detect if the pattern matches.  Its `-q` option stops it from outputting anything and `find` will use the exit status of the utility to determine whether to do the `-print` action or not.

Comment: Have you thought about penning a unix text ? IMO, Stephane & you  can team up and that would bring breadth, depth, and clarity into the picture which will be hard to match.